# Request ID is not available when App Launches after clicking Facebook notification

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, ios6, facebook-ios-sdk

A Facebook app is setup with iOS native app enabled with bundle id and App Store Id of another app.

Following are possible in the current scenario.

1.Sending an app request to a friend, 
2.The request badge appears in the friend's Facebook,
3. And clicking on the request launches my app.

This was the link i referred to implement this.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/send-requests-using-ios-sdk/#protip3

I am supposed to get a NSURL from these functions

```
– application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:
       OR
– application:handleOpenURL:
```

and the expected format is as follows.

```
fb[APP_ID]://authorize#expires_in=[ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRATION]
&access_token=[USER_ACCESS_TOKEN]
&target_url=https://apps.facebook.com/[APP_NAME_SPACE]/?request_ids=
[COMMA_SEPARATED_REQUESTIDs]&ref=notif&app_request_type=user_to_user
```

Here the  **request_ids** contains The id of app request send, and which can be used to get the data attached to the App Request.

Now my issue is that, I am not getting the NSURL in expected form, instead I get the following  format. So I am unable to find or use the request_ids.

```
fb[APP_ID]://authorize#expires_in=[ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRATION]
&access_token=[USER_ACCESS_TOKEN]
&target_url=https://apps.facebook.com/application.php?id=442634372448098
```

Comment: Have you set an APP_NAMESPACE in your app settings?

Comment: Well Thanks @CBroe, i fixed the issue i missed the APP_NAMESPACE in the settings

Comment: SO i need to set anything in IOS side or only setting namespace in FB page is enough

Comment: @AromalSasidharan : Can u give ur input?

Comment: @EXC_BAD_ACCESS  app name space is enough, it can be a simple name. no  changes required in IOS side