# APP_NAMESPACE facebook

Tags: facebook, namespaces, ios6, request

I'm new to Stack Overflow so please excuse me for any mistakes I could do in this question.  My problem is related to this one: [Request ID is not available when App Launches after clicking Facebook notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12853431/request-id-is-not-available-when-app-launches-after-clicking-facebook-notificati) .

I have exactly the same problem Aromal Sasidharan had, but in Facebook App Dashboard my App has a namespace set. Is there other place I need to fill it in?