# Request id missing in FB SDK 3.1 integration

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook

I am working on Facebook SDK 3.1. integration with native ios application.I am facing same issue which was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12853431/request-id-is-not-available-when-app-launches-after-clicking-facebook-notificati) (ie.. i am receving the notification as a friend.By clicking that i navigated to my app.But unable to get request ID in the target url )

As like answered in above question i set mt APP_NAMESPACE in my facebook application settings page.

Do i need to set anything other that or Do i use the same name space in any place of my ios app.
This is my settings page.
[image]

If i am missing something, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

APP_NAMESPACE is enough and is working for me

Comment: do we need to have any server page or anything for the App which we create in FB app settings page?

Comment: Any other extra permissions needed while login,ampassing as nil.Also one more doubt, am calling dialog like this, 
 
NSString *userDataStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:userDataDic];
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:msgStr,  @"message",
                             userDataStr, @"data",
                             @"app request",@"title",nil];
        [self.facebook dialog:@"apprequests"
                andParams:params
              andDelegate:self];

Comment: Do you have any idea on my question?

Comment: i am not sure whether i used additional permissions, any way try permissions  @"publish_actions",  @"manage_notifications"

Comment: you have face app installed in your device ? did you saved the settings in facebook website ? can you show the final dictionary created for params? is the request ids available in the delegate after dialog closes?

Comment: Ya.. request id is available in the sender end.after closing dialog, i logged in.my sender dic is here.
Params {
    data = "{\"listingUrl\":\"",\"address\":\"San Francisco, CA, 94109\",\"listingKey\":\"somedata\"}";
    message = "some text ";
    title = "app request";
} 
You are telling settings in developer.facebook.com right?

Comment: yes, you are right, note if are getting the request ids back in the delegate, then the permissions and code is fine.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21137/discussion-between-exc-bad-access-and-aromal-sasidharan)

Comment: ya.. i am getting... but in the receiver end the target url is like this "http://www.facebook.com/appcenter/demoapplicationforte?fb_source=notification".
Do i need to have a web server hosted on this url